# Connecting Azure Analysis service to Traffic Manager and Power BI

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-traffic-manager, azure-analysis-services

anyone has used a Traffic Manager above two Azure Analysis services for high availability and connect Traffic Manager to Power BI? we really need this to provide high availability but power BI doesn't seem to accept the Traffic Manager's URL 
we have followed this article to set things up.

[Alias Server Names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-server-alias)

thanks

Comment: Is [this](http://www.artisconsulting.com/blogs/greggalloway/2018/5/11/sending-users-to-the-geographically-nearest-azure-analysis-services) useful ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We worked out what the issue was - you can only connect the Traffic Manager to Power BI under HTTPS , we found this article very useful thanks to @NancyXiong-MSFT

[SendingUserstotheGeographicallyNearestAzureAnalysisServices](http://www.artisconsulting.com/blogs/greggalloway/2018/5/11/sending-users-to-the-geographically-nearest-azure-analysis-services)